# Data cannot be retrieved from $_SESSION in PHP

Tags: php, session

Hello i am a beginner in the PHP Language. I am finding it difficult to fetch / display data from a session in PHP. My login page works fine and the session is also being carried to the user page properly. But i get no data and no errors.

Below is my properly working login page script. I am not posting the page with the html elements since i have used `require_once` on it with the script below and it works fine.

```
<?php  
session_start();
require_once 'connection.php';

$err = array();
$errcnt = 0;

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (empty($_POST['usermail'])) {
        $err['verifyerr'] = "Please insert email";
        $errcnt++; 
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $err['passerr'] = "Please insert password";
        $errcnt++;
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['usermail'])) {
        $userquery = "SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE email = '".$_POST['usermail']."'";
        $userlookup = mysqli_query($connect, $userquery);
        $userfetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userlookup);

        if (empty($userfetch)) {
            $err['matcherr'] = "Invalid username";
            $errcnt++;
        }
        else {
            $passquery = "SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE email = '".$_POST['usermail']."' AND entrykey = '".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
            $passlookup = mysqli_query($connect, $passquery);
            $passfetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($passlookup);

            if (empty($passfetch)) {
                $err['invalidpass'] = "Invalid password";
                $errcnt++;
            }
            else {
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['usermail'];
                header("Location: http://localhost/Examination/user.php");
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And below is the user.php page where i am having the actual problem.

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once 'connection.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {


    echo $_SESSION['uid']  . '<br>';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed");
    }
    else {
        echo "All ok!";
    }
}
else {
    echo "not connected";
}


    //$queryoutput = "SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
    //$outquery = mysqli_connect($connect, $queryoutput);

    //if (!isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
    //header("Location: http://localhost/Examination/edulogin.php");
    //}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
    <?php  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        var_dump($row);
        echo "<hr />";
    }
    ?>


    <!--
    <h1></h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Firstname</h4></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Lastname</h4></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Gender</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Email</h4></td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td><h4>About You</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Country</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Interests</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h4>Image</h4></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <h3>Click here to <a href="http://localhost/Examination/userout.php">Logout</a></h3>
    -->
</body>
</html>
```

It even echoes the session properly where it shows the user's email and echoes 'All Ok'. But strangely no data is getting fetched and as i said no errors. Please if you know, tell me a solution. I will be highly obliged.

In case if you wanna take look at my connection.php page, here it is

```
<?php

define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'user_2');
$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: just on a sidenote, `md5()` is not encryption.  use [crypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are setting the `$_SESSION['uid']` with the email address, and then attempting to match a database record where the `id=email`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
```

If you are assigning the email address, then you should attempt to change your select query to (something like):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE email='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
```

Or assign the user id (`$_SESSION['uid'] = $userfetch['id']`) and then query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM studentdetails WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."'";
```

You are seeing `"All OK"`, because there is no error, just that there are no matching records (because the query is probably incorrect).

...And of course, make sure you protect yourself from injections!

Comment: so what wil be the solution sir?

Answer (score -2):

First of all you need to assign the data in `$_SESSION` array. You have already done this at

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $_POST['usermail'];
```

in your login page script.
Also check for the url. Is both (current and requesting one) are opening on same protocol i.e. `http://`?

Comment: this is an extremely confused answer that leads the OP no closer to any solution.